# Where Clause operator expected Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Hi guys I have a linq query as you can see below but my code give error like  ')' or operator expected  what is wrong with me?![This is my code][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsPQf.png

And also my query builder this code

```
string query = "";
foreach (var bud in budget)
{
    if (budget.Count >= 1)
    {
        if (bud == "1")
        {
            if (budget.Count>1)
            {
                query = "(Budget Between 20000 and 34999 "; 
            }
            else
            {
                query = "( Budget Between 20000 and 34999 )";
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code, not a link to an image of your code.

Comment: Your question is describing a compile time error, yet the image you posted is of code running in the debugger.  For it to be running, it would have had to have compiled successfully.

Comment: well I add my code completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to the Where() method cannot be a string, it must be a `Func<TSource, Boolean>`. Your method that generates the query will need to be defined as:

```
Expression<Func<Car, bool>> query = null;
```

Then whenever you want to set the value of query you would set it using:

```
query = car => car.Budget >= 20000 && car.Budget <= 34999;
```

Now you can use the `query` variable in your `Where()` method call.